# REACT and WebAPI CORS policy issue

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, webapi

I added CORS in my REACT server.js file and WebAPI startup.cs but still while retrieving the data through the API it gives me the below error.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/api/UserProfile. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

Here is my server.js  files CORS added

```
cors = require("cors"),

const corsOptions = { origin: "*",optionsSuccessStatus: 200 };

const app = exapp.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors(corsOptions)
```

WebAPI startup.cs code in ConfigureServices:

```
// add new services for CORS policy
             services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("REACT UI URL")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowCredentials()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

CORS policy in configure method:

```
 //added to allow CORS origin site
        app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i assume this "REACT UI URL" is just for show here and not what you're actually running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try calling `UseCors` in the first line inside `Configure`:

```cs
public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // KEEP THIS FIRST IN LINE OR ELSE WEB CLIENTS WILL NOT WORK!
    app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");
            
    ...
}
```

2. Make sure to put all origin domains inside WithOrigins:

```cs
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(
                         "http://localhost",
                         "https://localhost",
                         "https://<your-public-domain>")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowCredentials()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```